# Binary representation of data types in C

Tags: c, binary, integer, twos-complement

If I have a normal 32 bit int in C, how is the number represented in memory? Specifically, how is the sign stored?

At first I thought it would be sign and magnitude but then I remembered there would be + and - 0, so then I thought it could be stored in two's complement, however when using two's complement I ended up getting a maximum value of 4294967293 with the MSB set to 0 (I got this value by summing up everything from 2^31 to 2^0) which as we all know is wrong.

Comment: That's in fact implementation-defined. But two's complement is probably the most widely used these days.

Comment: You might want to read about [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: @mbratch Not in signed representations (neither two's complement nor sign-magnitude). The largest *unsigned* 32 bit integer is indeed `2^32-1`, but that's an entirely different matter.

Comment: @delnan oop, yeah sorry I was off by one bit. I should have said `31^1-1` (sum of `2^0 + ... + 2^30`.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard doesn't mandate two's complement, but it's by far the most common option (and I think even this is an understatement). The reason you arrive a 4 billion something, not at the correct `INT_MAX`, is an off-by-one error: You added the 32th bit as well. 2<sup>31</sup> is the value of the MSB (because the LSB has value 2<sup>0</sup>), so the correct value is the sum 2<sup>0</sup> + ... + **2<sup>30</sup>** = 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

Answer (score 1):

Even this is implementation defined, most machines use two's complement.

The problem is that your computation is wrong. Summing up 2^0 to 2^31 (which is 2^32 - 1, by the way) means that you use 32 bits. This is not correct: only 31 bits are used for the actual number. MSB has a special meaning and it has to do with the sign (is not really 'the sign'). So, you need to sum up from 2^0 to 2^30 (which is 2^31 - 1).